# Tensorflow/Keras/BERT MultiClass Text Classification Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, huggingface-transformers

I'm attempting to fine-tune the HuggingFace TFBertModel to be able to classify some text to a single label. I have the model up and running, however the accuracy is extremely low from the start. My expectation is that the accuracy would be high given that it is using the BERT pre-trained weights as a starting point. I was hoping to get some advice on where I'm going wrong.

I'm using the bbc-text dataset from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/yufengdev/bbc-text-categorization):

**Load Data**

```
df = pd.read_csv(open(<s3 url>),encoding='utf-8', error_bad_lines=False)
df = df.sample(frac=1)
df = df.dropna(how='any')
```

**Value Counts**

```
sport            511
business         510
politics         417
tech             401
entertainment    386
Name: label, dtype: int64
```

**Preprocessing**

```
def preprocess_text(sen):
# Convert html entities to normal
sentence = unescape(sen)

# Remove html tags
sentence = remove_tags(sentence)

# Remove newline chars
sentence = remove_newlinechars(sentence)

# Remove punctuations and numbers
sentence = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sentence)

# Convert to lowercase
sentence = sentence.lower()

return sentence


def remove_newlinechars(text):
    return " ".join(text.splitlines()) 

def remove_tags(text):
    TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
    return TAG_RE.sub('', text)

df['text_prepd'] = df['text'].apply(preprocess_text)
```

**Split Data**

```
train, val = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.30, shuffle=True, stratify=df['label'])
```

**Encode Labels**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train = np.asarray(le.fit_transform(train['label']))
y_val = np.asarray(le.fit_transform(val['label']))
```

**Define BERT input function**

```
# Initialise Bert Tokenizer
bert_tokenizer_transformer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

def create_input_array(df, tokenizer, args):
    sentences = df.text_prepd.values

    input_ids = []
    attention_masks = []
    token_type_ids = []

    for sent in tqdm(sentences):
        # `encode_plus` will:
        #   (1) Tokenize the sentence.
        #   (2) Prepend the `[CLS]` token to the start.
        #   (3) Append the `[SEP]` token to the end.
        #   (4) Map tokens to their IDs.
        #   (5) Pad or truncate the sentence to `max_length`
        #   (6) Create attention masks for [PAD] tokens.
        encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
            sent,  # Sentence to encode.
            add_special_tokens=True,  # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
            max_length=args.max_seq_len,  # Pad & truncate all sentences.
                pad_to_max_length=True,
                return_attention_mask=True,  # Construct attn. masks.
                return_tensors='tf',  # Return tf tensors.
            )

        # Add the encoded sentence to the list.
        input_ids.append(encoded_dict['input_ids'])

        # And its attention mask (simply differentiates padding from non-padding).
        attention_masks.append(encoded_dict['attention_mask'])

        token_type_ids.append(encoded_dict['token_type_ids'])

    input_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_ids)
    attention_masks = tf.convert_to_tensor(attention_masks)
    token_type_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(token_type_ids)

    return input_ids, attention_masks, token_type_ids
```

**Convert Data to Bert Inputs**

```
train_inputs = [create_input_array(train[:], tokenizer=tokenizer, args=args)]
val_inputs = [create_input_array(val[:], tokenizer=tokenizer, args=args)]
```

For `train_inputs, y_train` and `val_inputs, y_val` I then apply the below function which reshapes and converts to numpy arrays. The returned list from this function is then passed as arguments to the keras fit method. I realise this is a bit overkill converting to tf.tensors then to numpy, but I don't think this has an impact. I was originally trying to use tf.datasets but switched to numpy.

```
def convert_inputs_to_tf_dataset(inputs,y, args):
    # args.max_seq_len = 256
    ids = inputs[0][1]
    masks = inputs[0][1]
    token_types = inputs[0][2]

    ids = tf.reshape(ids, (-1, args.max_seq_len))
    print("Input ids shape: ", ids.shape)
    masks = tf.reshape(masks, (-1, args.max_seq_len))
    print("Input Masks shape: ", masks.shape)
    token_types = tf.reshape(token_types, (-1, args.max_seq_len))
    print("Token type ids shape: ", token_types.shape)

    ids=ids.numpy()
    masks = masks.numpy()
    token_types = token_types.numpy()

    return [ids, masks, token_types, y]
```

**Keras Model**

```
# args.max_seq_len = 256
# n_classes = 6
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', trainable=True, num_labels=n_classes)

input_ids_layer = Input(shape=(args.max_seq_len, ), dtype=np.int32)
input_mask_layer = Input(shape=(args.max_seq_len, ), dtype=np.int32)
input_token_type_layer = Input(shape=(args.max_seq_len,), dtype=np.int32)

bert_layer = model([input_ids_layer, input_mask_layer, input_token_type_layer])[0]
flat_layer = Flatten()(bert_layer)
dropout= Dropout(0.3)(flat_layer)
dense_output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(dropout)

model_ = Model(inputs=[input_ids_layer, input_mask_layer, input_token_type_layer], outputs=dense_output)
```

**Compile and Fit**

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
model.fit(inputs=..., outputs=..., validation_data=..., epochs=50, batch_size = 32, metrics=metric, verbose=1)


Epoch 32/50
1401/1401 [==============================] - 42s 30ms/sample - loss: 1.6103 - accuracy: 0.2327 - val_loss: 1.6042 -
 val_accuracy: 0.2308
```

As I'm using BERT, only a few epochs are necessary, so I was expecting something much higher than 23% after 32 epochs.

Comment: Please include the data preparation code as well, i.e. constructing `x_train` and `x_test`.

Comment: Done, I've added detail in 'Convert data to bert inputs' section.

Comment: This line `ids = inputs[0][1]`, the `ids` are the first element i.e. it should be `ids = inputs[0][0]`. Further, you should fit the `LabelEncoder` only one time, i.e. just use `transform` (and not `fit_transform`) on validation labels.

Comment: Further, you might need to use a lower learning for the optimizer (the default is 1e-3). Otherwise, the fine-tuning process might get disrupted. Try: `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)` (or even lower than that, say 1e-5).

Comment: Epoch 1/5
1401/1401 [==============================] - 58s 42ms/sample - loss: 1.2287 - accuracy: 0.7951 - val_loss: 
0.9828 - val_accuracy: 0.9487

Comment: Just curious: are you using GPU to fine-tune your model? If so, what's the GPU model?

Comment: Yes I am using a Google Cloud instance with a Tesla P100 gpu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is in this line: `ids = inputs[0][1]`. Actually, the ids are the first element of `inputs[0]`; so it should be `ids = inputs[0][0]`.

But there is also another problem which might result in inconsistent validation accuracy: you should fit the `LabelEncoder` only one time to construct the label mapping; so you should use the `transform` method, instead of `fit_transform`, on **validation** labels.

Further, don't use both `softmax` activation and `from_logits=True` in loss function simultaneously; only use either of them (see [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/73182/28035) for more info).

Another point is that you might need to use a lower learning rate for the optimizer. The default learning rate of Adam optimizer is 1e-3, which might be too high considering that you are **fine-tuning a pretrained model**. Try a lower learning rate, say 1e-4 or 1e-5; e.g. `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)`. A high learning rate for fine-tuning a pretrained model might destroy the learned weights and disrupts fine-tuning process (due to the large gradient values generated, especially at the start of fine-tuning process).

Comment: Also, isn't TFBertForSequenceClassification built for binary classification? It should work better than 23% accuracy, but if you need a multiclass classifier, shouldn't you change the loss function?

Comment: @Paul No, it's not only for binary classification; and also the OP is using categorical cross-entropy as the loss function which is the right choice for multi-class classification.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood all your steps especially with tokenizer. I don't know where the issue could be but it can be done is an much easier way. Higgungface transformer offer you some easy solution to do text classification:

```
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
```

there is also some function to put the data in the format expected by the model:

```
glue_convert_examples_to_features
```

You will need to do a deep dive in the doc to see all parameters you can set like the number of classes, type of glue task for preprocessing ...

You can find some example below: https://pypi.org/project/transformers/

Comment: Thank you - I've refreshed my situation as it is at the moment. I've used HuggingFace as suggested, and my inputs come from the encode_plus method in the HF library. I've also switched out my dataset for a well-known one to try and get some clarity on the model. Accuracy starts at 23% but it doesn't improve at all even after 32 epochs. Validation loss stays the same too from the start.